# Change default date format Dynamic Text or add option to Dynamic text Menu

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dynamic-text

I frequently use the Dynamic text for date saved in my map templates but my new boss prefers a different format (February 2nd, 2016).  I have the short code he prefers but would like to change it to the default format or add it as an option to the dynamic text menu under the insert menu.  The code is:

```
<dyn type="date" format="MMMM"/> <dyn type="date" format="yy"/>, <dyn type="date" format="yyy"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you could do this using ArcObjects, but in the absence of that I think your only option may be to consult ArcGIS Ideas.

There does not seem to be an [existing idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/apex/ideaSearchResults?s=dynamic%20text%20date&searchButton=search) for this so if you decide to submit one then I think its title should be something like:

> Allow users to customize default formatting string for Dynamic Text
>   types like Current Date

It should be noted that the formatting string you provided displays `February 2, 2016` and not your required `February 2nd, 2016`